# Prevent logs being printed on console

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing script using Ruby Selenium-webdriver. After running the script, I receive following logs on console -

```
 LOG addons.manager: Application has been upgraded
 LOG addons.xpi: startup
 LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
 LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
 LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges
 LOG addons.xpi-utils: Opening database
 LOG addons.xpi-utils: Creating database schema
 LOG addons.xpi: New add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com installed in app-profile
 LOG addons.xpi: New add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} installed in app-global
 LOG addons.xpi: New add-on {BBDA0591-3099-440a-AA10-41764D9DB4DB} installed in winreg-app-global
 LOG addons.xpi: New add-on fiddlerhook@fiddler2.com installed in winreg-app-global
 LOG addons.xpi: Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
 LOG addons.xpi-utils: Updating add-on states
 LOG addons.xpi-utils: Writing add-ons list
 LOG addons.xpi: shutdown
 LOG addons.xpi-utils: shutdown
 LOG addons.xpi-utils: Database closed
 LOG addons.xpi: startup
 LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
 LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
 LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges
 LOG addons.xpi: No changes found
```

I don't want these logs to be printed on console, I only want whatever my program is returning to STDOUT, to be printed on console. Is there any way we can prevent these logs in Ruby? In Python, we can do this using following -

```
import traceback
Settings.ActionLogs=False
Settings.InfoLogs=False
Settings.DebugLogs=False
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in console first, then run your code:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = nil
```

this will work in console.

Comment: It didn't work. I also tried following in my code -require 'logger'

require 'active_record'
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = nil